# The jQuery CSS effect is lost when render :action=>edit, how to get rid of it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my UI **edit.html**, I have

```
<input type='text', id='name'></input>
```

and I have

```
<p>Name:</p>
```

The, I have a **javascript** file which will use **jQuery** to **css** the style of the UI:

```
$('<p></p>').css('margin-left', '20px').insertAfter($('#name'));
```

The above CSS will locate  `<p>` element to be located 20px the right side of `<input>`.

Everything is fine when my app firstly load the **edit.html** page, the **CSS** style is there.

**BUT**, when the model validation is **failed**, and in my **controller**, I use

`render :action=>edit`,

the **CSS** style feature is **lost**;

**however** if my **controller** use

`redirect_to :action=>edit, :id=>@user`,

the CSS style is there as expected.

Why my **jquery** defined **CSS** style is lost if I use `render :action=>edit` to render this page. How to get rid of this? I would like to use `render :action=>edit` while keep my jQuery defined CSS taking effect.

Comment: Do you have any conditional javascript includes / different layouts with different JS files?

Comment: Yes, I have the logic in my js that  "if it is in editing page then the code takes effect". But I DO navigate to the editing page, the only difference is use "render" & "redirect_to" which gives different result. The js code seems not take effect if I use 'render' in my controller, that's my problem.

Comment: what is the exact condition? Render & redirect do different things - redirect actually does the action, whereas render simply shows the view

Comment: The exact condition is 'pathEndsWith('\\d/edit$')', in my js, I will check if this condition is true or false. if it is true, the following jQuery code should take effect. So, both 'render' and 'redirect_to' navigate to editing page, why 'render' makes the js code lost its functionalities?